# simulating a click on a <input type=“file” /> jQuery, Opera

Tags: jquery, file, file-upload, opera

i have form with display none and input type file in it, I also made ​​a button. when you click on it should open download dialog box. This combination works in all browsers except Opera. Begins to work if to remove display: none;

```
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='' style="display: none;">
    <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
</form>
<input type="button" id="upload" value="upload">
```

Jquery:

```
$('#upload').on("click", function () {
    $('#photoimg').click();
});
```

Please explain, how to avoid this.

Comment: If it works without `display:none`, then do that.  Try using `visibility:hidden` instead.

Answer (score 6):

It would be better if you use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display:none`

or you can try with pure CSS. for example:

```
#photoimg {
   left: -99999px
}
```

or

```
#photoimg {
   z-index: -999
}
```

or

```
#photoimg {
   width: 0px
}
```

or something like that

Comment: left margin of -99999px? a page with width of `99999px`?

Comment: You cannot style file input elements. That's why one does these hacks with buttons that delegate the click.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the file input element `display: none` you can do this:

```
<div style="width:0;height:0;overflow:hidden;">
    <form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
        <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" accept="image/*"
           onchange="document.getElementById('imageform').submit();" />
    </form>
</div>
<button id="upload" onclick="document.getElementById('photoimg').click();">
Upload</button>
```